# removal of mold in sump well that doesn't have a pump

Tags: mold

How do I remove mold from the sump well water and on the sides of the well and also return the water to clear and not cloudy

Answer (score 2):

Spray the sides of the well with dilute bleach periodically (maybe a 4:1 water:bleach ratio) and pour some straight bleach in the standing water.  Start with just a little and add more as needed (or make the mix less dilute).